# Set Xcode Autolayout default to superview over safe area

Tags: xcode

*Please don't mark as duplicate as similar questions don't cover the actual point of the question: Changing the default behavior.*

Pretty much every day I set constraints and then have to manually set them from safe are to superview for example for bottom/top container view. This is pretty time costly and fairly annoying.

Is there a way to set the default behavior to superview over safe area?
I'm fully aware of how to change them and also how to change it "one time" before attaching them as described in several similar questions over here.

[image]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.